# HTML CSS Layout in Outlook 2016

Tags: html, css, outlook

I want to create an email that contains two buttons, one to approve a request and another one to reject that request.
Unfortunately, Outlook doesn't want to show them as I want it to.

[image: Approve / Reject Button in Outlook]

```
<table style="width: 250px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a style="display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:100%" href="ApproveLink"><div style="padding:15px 32px 15px 32px;background:green;border:1px solid #ccc;vertical-align:middle;width:100px;text-align:center;height:45px;"><span style="color:white;font-weight:bold;">Approve</span></div></a></td>
<td><a style="display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:100%" href="RejectLink"><div style="padding:15px 32px 15px 32px;background:red;border:1px solid #ccc;vertical-align:middle;width:100px;text-align:center;height:45px;"><span style="color:white;font-weight:bold;">Reject</span></div></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Intention: The Button has a small border (which works). The div that exposes that border is the containment of an  Element (so the whole area could be clicked on). Additionally, the whole area should be filled with color (red and green).

Unfortunately, the clickable area is restricted to the text (Approve, Reject) and a few pixels above and below but not the whole "button-area". Additionally, as you can see, the color does not span to the whole area, too.

In a normal html editor, everything works nicely so Outlook is the deal breaker - but how do I get it to work?

Comment: So how is it going with you?

Comment: @xxxmatko sorry, forgot to mark the question as answered - Thanks for your effort! :)

Comment: Your welcome, happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links or buttons in Outlook email are very tricky. The best way to create link, that looks like a button is to use Vector Markup Language (VML) within an Outlook-specific conditional comment as a fallback for Microsoft Outlook, and styling on the link itself for most email clients. Like this:

```
<table width="250px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <!--[if mso]>
          <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="ApproveLink" style="height:36px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" arcsize="3%" strokecolor="green" fillcolor="green">
            <w:anchorlock/>
            <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold">Approve</center>
          </v:roundrect>
        <![endif]-->
        <a href="ApproveLink" style="mso-hide:all">Approve</a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <!--[if mso]>
          <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="RejectLink" style="height:36px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" arcsize="3%" strokecolor="red" fillcolor="red">
            <w:anchorlock/>
            <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold">Reject</center>
          </v:roundrect>
        <![endif]-->
        <a href="RejectLink" style="mso-hide:all">Reject</a>
      </div>
    </td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Disadvantage of this technique is that, the with and height of the button have to be set, on the other hand the whole area is clickable.

There are other techniques like padding-based or border-based buttons, but this time you are facing the same issue that the whole area is not clickable.

```
<table width="250px%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="green" style="padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px; border-radius:3px" align="center">
                <a href="ApproveLink" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">Approve</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="red" style="padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px; border-radius:3px" align="center">
                <a href="RejectLink" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">Reject</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Some very good info you can find here: https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design